# How to load image in css file using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs (Nextjs), i put my images folder in "public" folder and in "style.css" file i changed path but image is not showing,Where i am wrong ? Here is my current code

```
background-image: url('/hero.jpg');
```

Comment: there is a typo `background-image: url('./hero.jpg')`; add `.`

Comment: @debugger i am getting error "Module not found: Can't resolve './hero.jpg'"

Comment: I think you are using wrong path. Try using `<img src="">`

Comment: "Here is my current code" - is this your current code in your CSS file or in a JS file? More context (i.e. code around this) would help to answer this.

Comment: @Rylee my current code in "css" file ( already mentioned)

Comment: @debugger actually i am working in "css" file not js file

Comment: Need more information on the structure of your app. There's some existing similar questions that may help you out [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53793957/cannot-load-background-image-in-react) [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65125891/cant-resolve-images-img-2-jpg-in-e-react-react-demo-src) [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625964/react-css-cant-use-image-from-public)

Comment: Please provide the actual folder structure of the `public` folder. If the images are contained within another folder then that needs to be reflected on the path to the image.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Nextjs app, your styles are in a styles folder so your path should be

```
background-image: url('../public/{...maybe some folders in between}/hero.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

first, import your local image into the expected file.

```
import bg from [your path] '../../images/bg.png';
```

```
<div style={{background: `url(${bg})`}}>
... ... ...
</div>
```